# Is there possiblitiy to fast refresh oracle database without materialized view log?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My remote database table that I have only read access (READ only) have no materialized view log. I want to be able to add only new data as done by fast refresh in materialized view. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer from the doc at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#REPLN354 :

> You can perform fast refreshes of materialized views only when the master table or master materialized view has a materialized view log.